# Script Batch, run external exe and get his PID

Tags: batch-file, batch-processing

I have a batch script A. This script run an .exe application and after a while, the script A stop the .exe application.
My problem is I run my script A in several shell. Consequently, I execute several times simultaneously the same .exe application (but with different PID)

My question is, in batch, how can I run an external .exe and get his PID ? 
If I run the exe and I catch his PID, I can stop the "good" .exe.

Comment: AFAIK executables have no gender.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
For /f "tokens=2 delims=;= " %A in ('wmic process call create notepad.exe ^| findstr /c:ProcessId') Do Echo %A
```

For is the command to get output from a command. WMIC returns the PID for programs it starts.

```
 wmic process call create notepad.exe
```

In a batch file use `%%A` rather than `%A` when typing.

Comment: Thanks for your answer ! I'm not very good in batch scripting, can you provide me an exemple where the batch execute the .exe in the current directory ?

Comment: I find =) For /f "tokens=2 delims=;= " %A in ('wmic process call create "C:\pathtotestbat\test.bat" ^| findstr /c:ProcessId') Do Echo %A